# Android Studio Gradle Plugin 7.0.1 seems to have broken android permissions lint checks

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-permissions

Yesterday I allowed Android Studio to upgrade the Gradle Plugin to 7.0.1 and since then my project is displaying errors on any code that requires either:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Strangley, code that requires

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

is not showing in error.

The above lines are copied from my `AndroidManifest.xml` and if I click the suggested fixes in the ALT-ENTER popup to add the permissions it simply duplicates the lines in the manifest and teh error remains.

I have tried resyncing Gradle, Cleaning and rebuilding project and even invalidating caches and restarting, but the errors in the IDE remain.

Building and running the app on AVD devices or a real device works fine.

How can I fix this? Just changing the Gradle Plugin version and Gradle version in Project Structure doesn't seem to help.

Update: I've also tried wrapping the code that shows the errors in an `if` statement that checks that teh permission has been granted and that makes no difference, so rather than this being a complex Lint check it does seem like a simple misfiring of the API vs Manifest permissions checks...